# How do I host a Google gadget? How does it work?

Tags: ajax, google-gadget

I just spent 5 hours by checking Google gadgets websites and FAQs, but I still have no idea how to host a gadget.

What I've figured from reading the Google documentation:

1. I can write gadgets with XML, JavaScript etc..
2. Gadgets can be added to iGoogle etc..
3. Google can host the gadgets for you.
4. Gadgets can be hosted anywhere else???

All of the above information doesn't answer my question. For instance, with jQuery or Dojo Toolkit, I can download the JavaScript framework and use it. With Google gadgets, I can not find a download link for a framework. Why? Does Google provide its framework? If not, why does the documentation indicate that gadgets can be hosted anywhere? I am totally confused.

A brief explanation or some helpful links are very welcome! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: hi, having the same problem as you, have you finally found out if the gadgets can be created and hosted on your own website? can you build in the hosting functionality into your own website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a gadget defining an xml spec [(reference)](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/reference.html) and host it anywhere you want (ie. your [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) public folder). The xml will have a Content section with the html for the gadget. There you can include script tags with any js library you want to use (ie. jquery, dojo, your own js files).

If you want to install the gadget in iGoogle, you need to go to 'Add Stuff' and instead from picking a gadget from the directory, you click on 'add rss or gadget' link and enter the url to your gadget xml file. The container (in this case iGoogle, but could be Orkut, MySpace, etc) will pull your gadget spec and render the gadget.

[Here's a good place to start with gadget development](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/basic.html)

Comment: Your answer repeats what the user already knows as he said in 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Yeah and the second commenter repeats what the first commented already said.

Comment: I agree with the previous commenters. Doesn't answer the question about how the gadget can be hosted anywhere ie. not on google sites

Comment: I think the confusion might stem from differentiating between hosting you created gadgets on you own site as against, rendering the gadget on your own site. Alejandro addresses that first problem but I wonder if the OP did not want to know how his site can be a gadget container and display gadgets

Answer (score 6):

I've  just been trying to get my head around all this myself and most of the information out there seems to be about building gadgets, not the infrastructure of hosting them.

Essentially the way it seems to work is that you need:

1. Somewhere to host the XML file that defines the gadget. This can be anywhere on the web.
2. A Google Gadget container - you tell this the URL of the XML file for your gadget and it does the magic to turn your XML into a rendering gadget. Examples are iGoogle http://www.google.com/ig, Google Friend Connect http://www.google.com/friendconnect/ and Shindig http://shindig.apache.org/
3. A site to actually display the Gadget - this can either be a site with the functionality inbuilt such as iGoogle or can be any website on which you put the embed HTML for the gadget. This embed HTML will vary according to the container. If you go to a gadget in iGoogle, that you've either added or is in their directory, you can see the embed code for the gadget. For Google Friend Connect, there's a snippet of HTML and Javascript that you can use, in which you put the URL of the XML file and your Google Friend Connect site id.

The fact that some sites such as iGoogle do 1, 2 and 3 is I think what initially made things slightly confusing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Beside iGoogle and others Gadgets containers, you can also host gadgets on any page where you can include a script. Google has a site that will generate for you the script that will show the gadget on your page: http://www.google.com/webmasters/gadgets/foryourpage/

The generated code uses www.gmodules.com. However I've not found much more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think its late to answer the question. Here are few comments which could help others.

Google can host the gadgets for you?? - Yes

Gadgets can be hosted anywhere else??? - Yes. You can host on your own **server** or **dropbox public folder** does work too.

The easiest way to create and host gadget is to use google gadget editor. Which does all we need to have our own google gadget.

The link to  google gadget editor is http://www.google.com/ig/ifr?url=gge.xml. Here you can edit and host the gadget. Below are the screenshots for reference.

Once you've got something you want to test, click the file menu, and select 'SAVE' as shown below.

[image]

Once you've saved (and selected a good name for your xml file), you'll see it changes from hello.xml to something else.

[image]

Then, it's as easy as doing a right-click and saving the location to the clipboard. Here's how that looks in Firefox.

[image]

That's it. The link to ur google gadget will be in ur clipboard. Which looks something like this..,
**http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/117733801868661729078/my-first-gadget.xml**